# Issue with Primeng input number - when enter 99,999,999,999,999.99

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am trying to customize the input number field to accept the maximum number to "99,999,999,999,999.99". But once I enter the max value, then automatically the value flipped to "99,999,999,999,999.98". How to fix this?

I can see the same behavior on the DEMO page also.

1. Goto: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/inputnumber
2. Try 'User Locale'

Comment: Too many significant digits.  There is a limit to the precision of javascript's numbers.  Approx 15 digits.

Comment: If you want to use bigger numbers use the [`bigint`](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_bigints.html) datatype which can hold any number but only integer values. But e.g if that value would be some amount of money in euros just store it as cents and get rid of the decimal values that way.